# Why does a certain CSV file import properly into LibreOffice but not into Mathematica 10.0?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, csv-format

I'm working on a project involving data manipulation and it involves working with CSV files.

I know that the files are properly formatted as when I import them into LibreOffice, all of the columns contain the information they are meant to.
When I import the files into Mathematica (10.0) however, data from the 45th column (for example) shows up in the 1st column.

I'm using:

```
    Import["filename.csv","Data"]
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Thank you~

Comment: Could you provide one of the csv files in question? I never had problems importing csv files

Comment: Try `Import["filename.csv","CSV"]`

Comment: Here's a link to the file: http://expirebox.com/download/13fef09bf65bcc7491068139c6b637ee.html 

I tried using "CSV" instead of "Data" but I ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Some of the comma-separated-values contain new lines, so this is not a valid CSV file.

Comment: Did you try `Import["file_exported_from_LibreOffice.csv"]`

Comment: @Coolwater I tried to do that but it too did not work.

Comment: @rhermans Is this due to the empty B and C columns?

Comment: Just to let you guys know I removed the listing notes column and all the issues were resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the existing comma-separated-values, fields, containing "new lines" are the offending elements in your file.

If you do

```
Length /@ Import["data.csv"]
```

> {64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 1, 1, 25, 64, 64, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 1, 2, 2, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 12, 1, 25, 64, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64}

when all records should be of 64 fields.

CSV is not a general standard, so Mathematicas's implementation is as good as any other in principle. Nevertheless, [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) defines the following

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx

where CRLF stands for "carriage return" and "line feed" characters.

So to answer the question: Why? Because Mathematica is ignoring that CSV "feature" and considering CRLF within quotations marks as the end of the line record.

Comment: As a comment, I think that a better implementation would be to offer the option to use or ignore the feature of CRLF protected by quotation marks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to resolve the CRLF problem.

```
data = Import[fname, "Text"];
StringReplacePart[data, "\[Wolf]", 
  StringPosition[data, "\n" ~~ DigitCharacter]];
StringReplace[%, "\n" -> ""];
StringReplace[%, "\[Wolf]" -> "\n"];
data2 = ImportString[%, "CSV"];
```

First, I import the file as a single text string.  I notice in the file that all of the 'valid' linefeeds are immediately followed by a digit character (from cell 1) so we replace all the valid linefeeds with a character that is not in the original string (say, the Mathematica wolf).  Then delete all the remaining linefeeds and reinsert the valid ones.  `data2` now contains 59 rows, each with 64 columns.

Comment: This solution only works because the new records always starts with a DigitCharacter... Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking of using a regular expression with Shortest[ "\"" ~~ ... EndOfLine ... ~~ "\""] or something along those lines, but to no avail.... Not to mention that there could be multiple EndOfLine within double quotes...

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a more general solution. It is based on regular expressions (or here, string patterns). The idea is to look for the shortest strings in the file that begins with double-quote, ends with double quotes, does not contain any double quote, but can contain one or many EndOfLine. As it is a CSV, there are comma before the double-quote (thus, this solution cannot be applied if the double-quote string can be the first field in the input).
First, lets define a string pattern with any text or EndOfLine:

```
textenter = Repeated[Except["\""] .. ~~ EndOfLine];
```

It can contain any number of CRLF as long as some text preceeds them.

The second step is to locate all the substrings in a string variable, say `csvstring`, that match a comma, a double-quote, a textenter pattern, some final text before another double-quote:

```
u = StringCases[cvsstring,{Shortest[",\"" ~~ x : textenter ~~ y___ ~~ "\""]}];
```

Next, replace all the occuences found in `u` with the same but the CRLF replaced by some character (here I used [Wolf] just for the sake of the example):

```
v = StringReplace[cvsstring, Map[# :> StringReplace[#, "\n" -> "\[Wolf]"] &, u]];
```

This is it; convert `v` as any csv text string containing strings delimited with double quote with:

```
ImportString[v, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""]
```

This can be made into a function with:

```
RemoveInnerCRLF[cvsstring_] := Module[{u, v},
  u = StringCases[cvsstring,{Shortest[",\"" ~~ x : textenter ~~ y___ ~~ "\""]}];
  v = StringReplace[cvsstring, Map[# :> StringReplace[#, "\n" -> "\[Wolf]"] &, u]];
  ImportString[v, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""]
  ]
```

which you can use with

```
reg = RemoveInnerCRLF[Import[myfile, "Text"]];
```

where `myfile` is some indication of a file that needs to be imported.