# Exporting Table format and strings not enclosed in quotes

Tags: export, text

The help file for [`format/Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) says very clearly

> "By default, Export delimits text fields containing the field separator with double-quote characters."

A simple test shows this statement is not true:

```
data = {{"ab", 1}, {"dd", 2}};
Export["test.txt", data, "Table"]
```

I know it can be corrected by

```
Export["test.txt", data, "Table","TextDelimiters" -> "\""]
```

but again, the behaviour should be by default and this does not seem right. (also note that changing file-type to `dat` does not help).

This is happening on Mathematica 11.3 for Linux.

**Can anyone confirm this is a bug?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

The documentation is fine, there is no bug, use `"TSV"` instead of `"Table"`.

---

### Longer explanation

The [documentation for `Table` reads](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html)

> By default, `Export` delimits text fields containing the field separator
>   with double-quote characters.

Example when the field **does not** contain a field separator (`"\t"`)

```
ExportString[{{"ab", 1}, {"dd", 2}}, "Table"]
(* 
"ab\t1\ndd\t2"
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example when a field **does** contain a field separator (`"\t"`)

```
ExportString[{{"a\tb", 1}, {"dd", 2}}, "Table"]
(* 
"\"a\tb\"\t1\ndd\t2"
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And therefore the behaviour is exactly as described in the documentation.

---

### Alternative

If you want quotation marks always and by default, use `"TSV"`

```
ExportString[{{"ab", 1}, {"dd", 2}}, "TSV"]
(*
"\"a\tb\"\t1\n\"dd\"\t2\n"
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Note

In a related topic [discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58454/10397), formats like `"CSV"` are not a general standard and  Mathematicas's implementation is as good as any other in principle. Nevertheless, [RFC 4180](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) defines the following

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>         should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>         bb","ccc" CRLF
>         zzz,yyy,xxx

where CRLF stands for "carriage return" and "line feed" characters.

But Mathematica ignores that interpretation when doing `Import` and line or fields separators within quotations marks may be considered real separators instead of part of the fields.